# Translate to Latin: Merciful Jesus, have pity on me

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, ecclesiastical-latin

How would this be properly translated to Latin?

Comment: How would this variation of the original post be translated: “Merciful Jesus, I place all my trust in You.”

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Pie Iesu, miserere mei**

will do.

The idea in full can be found in some versions of the [Ave Verum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ave_verum_corpus). Note that the linked article translates *pie* as *holy*, though it usually also means *benevolent, kind* (hence *merciful*) when referred to the Lord.

Alternatives to *pie* commonly used in ecclesiastical Latin are: *piíssime* (the superlative of *pie*), or *multae misericordiae* (of great mercy, [Ps. 102](https://www.vatican.va/archive/bible/nova_vulgata/documents/nova-vulgata_vt_psalmorum_lt.html#PSALMUS%20103)), or even *dives in misericordia* (rich in mercy,) if you want to use a more specific word for mercy (misericordia) in the title for Jesus.

The separate ideas (*merciful Jesus* on one hand and *have pity on me* on the other) are omnipresent in Liturgy, the Scripture, and elsewhere. For *have pity on me* the (almost fixed) formula is *miserere mei*, unless you want to make a nuanced distinction between *pity* and *mercy* that my English skills are too limited to catch.

The verbal form *miserere* (*have mercy*) is found 18 times in the Gospels and is always directed to Jesus or some other holy person, followed by a personal pronoun in genitive. Of these *mei* (*of me*, as is idiomatic in Latin) is by far the most common. Among these, it is noteworthy the call by the blind man in Lk 18:38,

> **Iesu, fili David, miserere mei!**
> *[Jesus son of David, have pity on me](https://www.catholic.org/bible/book.php?id=49&bible_chapter=18)*.

Comment: Whenever I see "Pie Iesu," I think "Pie Iesu Domine, dona eis requiem"

Comment: *Cor Jesu sacratissimum et misericors, miserere nobis* means "Heart of Jesus most sacred and merciful, have mercy on us". It's a common and very short Latin prayer, for what it's worth.